# How to override a WordPress plugin file

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I am trying to override a mundipagg-payments plugin file. Its location is placed at:

```
/wp-content/plugins/woo/mundipagg-payments/templates/checkout/main.php
```

I have created the following path inside my child theme:

```
/wp-content/themes/sober-child/woo-mundipagg-payments/checkout/main.php
```

The problem is that the new path inside my child theme does not change the actual content of the plugin.
When I try to place the code inside the plugin folder I get the expected result.

How can I make that work inside my child theme?

Comment: Have you applied locate_template( function?

Comment: I have not tried that.

Comment: That should be applied in the theme, then only it will search for templates in your theme - Refer wc_get_template function

Comment: And how can I do that exactly?

Comment: https://www.ibenic.com/include-or-override-wordpress-templates/